# Unable to clear the form after login on ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ionic-framework, autologin

I am trying to use the code from [here](https://calendee.com/2014/12/26/validation-in-ionic-framework-apps-with-ngmessages/)

I am trying to design a login form in Ionic but I am facing two issues:

1.Cant understand why have they used 2 submits in the example:

```
<form name="signinForm" novalidate="" ng-submit="signIn(signinForm)">
```

and:

```
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signIn(user)">
```

2.I get an error when I am trying to clean the fields using:

```
$scope.user.remove();
```

The error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

My code looks like:

```
$scope.$on('event:auth-loginConfirmed', function() {
    $scope.user.remove();
    $state.go('app.placeslists');
});


$scope.signIn = function(form) {
    if (form.$valid) {
        AuthenticationService.login($scope.user);
    }
};
```

Comment: does your user object have `remove()` method?

Comment: amm I just want to remove data from scop I see its related to scop from template...http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/OPRzLy

Comment: That's my Codepen sample.  Thanks for pointing out the double submit!  I've fixed it.

Comment: @Justin can you also add to template the error handling like user/pass incorrect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Cant understand why have they used 2 submits in the example:

I cannot be sure why that coder chose to add 2 submit events, but I just removed the `ng-click` and it works fine, because we are not requiring the `user` object, since it already is in the scope. So you can remove `ng-click` from the button.

> 2. I get an error when I am trying to clean the fields using:

This should work to empty your fields:

```
$scope.user = { username: '', password: '' };
```

This code will empty your `user` scope.

`remove()` won't work like this in AngularJS.

Comment: $scope.user = ''; this isnt working for my, its undefined when I do $scope.user.

Comment: It worked for me very much fine. Where did you add that code? It should be added in the SigninController, immediately **above** the `$state.go` function. Check this forked Codepen, it works fine - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPPvba

Comment: the issue was that I didnt do  $scope.user = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };

Comment: also this incorrect to do it like $scope.user = ''; because next time on login it will not work!

Comment: Okay, I will edit my answer.  Thank you. Although, on Codepen, I had tried the code I answered with, it worked fine.